# EchartsJS: xAxis categories with correct proportion

Tags: angular, charts, echarts

In echarts (https://www.echartsjs.com/en/index.html) you can set the xAxis type to "category" and to "value" (amongst other types).

```
public series = [
  { name: 'Example A', data: [5, 3, 4, 2, 1], type: 'line' }
];

public Axis = {
 type: 'Category',
 name: 'location',
 data: ['Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Erlangen', 'Munich', 'Bremen']
};
```

This will match series.data with xAxis.data in the provided order (Berlin -> 5, Hamburg -> 3 etc.) resulting in a graph that starts at 5, goes down to 3, then up to 4 again and so on. This also means each of these categories are equally distributed along the graph: There is always the same space between each location here.

You could also set the xAxis.type to 'value' instead:

```
public Axis = {
 type: 'value',
 name: 'distance',
};
```

This would automatically create an x-Axis ranging from 1-5, resulting into a match of 1 -> 1,  2 -> 2 and so on, basically creating a linear line graph. Since this xAxis is auto generated it would take different data point distances into account while creating the 'categories', meaning that there would be a big space between a category of 1 and a category of 800, while in the first example that space would be equally distributed among all possible x axis categories.

What I would like to have though is the best of both worlds:

If I would change my category data from locations like "[Berlin, Hamburg..]" to distances like [100, 200, 250, 300, 500], I would still want them as categories so that the first value of my series.data array matches the first value of my xAxis.data array (5 --> 100, 3 --> 200, 4 --> 250, etc.) but I would also want the category '500' to be further away from the category '300' while category '250' would be rather close to category '300'.

Is there any way to achieve this with EchartsJS?